# Restricting / Protecting Topics with MQTT and Solace

Tags: mqtt, message-queue, publish-subscribe, solace, solace-mq

I'm working toward an event-driven simulation infrastructure using Solace's PubSub+ for MQTT as a broker. I have a type of control message topic prefixed by `control/`.

Is there anyway to protect/restrict publish access to this topic prefix (or specific topics in general) to one authenticated user (i.e. the controller node)?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes indeed there is! What you are inquiring about is configuring access control list under the Client Authorization. Check out more information about ACLs in the [docs here](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/ACL.htm#mc-main-content). ACLs are configured on the broker management console, so whether you are using a local broker (via docker for example), cloud solution (Solace Cloud) or an appliance, you access your ACLs from the "Access Control" tab and configure your users and topic subscriptions. You can also check out the [Solace Community](https://solace.community/discussion/453/solace-cloud-and-basic-auth) forum where you can see a bunch of people asking questions about Solace related concepts and messaging in general.

Note: if you are using MQTT to connect to the broker, you can create a username on the broker with predefined authentication. You will use this authentication during your mqtt client connection.